# database field data not appearing in form textbox in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

i have this code in PHP and a database sql.. the situation is .. if i type the 1, 2 or 3 (productID) .. the textbox will be populated and field with database values.. but when i run the program.. fortunately it has no errors.. but when i type the id or 1 and click the submit button.. it doesnt get the neccessary values.. sorry for this im a complete newbie and im practicing PHP for a while now.. any help will do.. thank you..

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
header("Location: index.php");
}

$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow = mysql_fetch_array($res);
?>

<?php
require('dbconnect.php');
$id = (isset($_REQUEST['productID']));

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblstore WHERE productID = '$id'");
$sql = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if(!$result){
die("Error: Data not found");
} else {
$brandname = $sql['brandname'];
$price = $sql['price'];
$stocks = $sql['stocks'];
}

?>

<html>
<body>
<p>
hi' <?php echo $userRow['username']; ?>&nbsp;<a href="logout.php?logout">Sign Out</a>
</p>

<form method="post">
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td>Search Apparel:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="search" name="productID" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Brandname:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="brandname" value="<?php echo $brandname; ?>"/ </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Price:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $price; ?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Stocks:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="stocks" value="<?php echo $stocks; ?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: first off, this isn't how you use `$id = (isset($_REQUEST['productID']));` and it's not throwing errors, because you're most likely not checking for them on both PHP and MySQL sides of things.

Comment: oh.? maan..i need a lot of practice... anyway.. is there a solution to it..? thanks again..

Comment: Try to make your question simpler. Just try to make a sample where you read a simple sql value from db.Test you can connect db first.

Answer (score 0):

your getting the id incorrectly, you have:

```
<?php
$_REQUEST['productID']=8; //for testing
$id = (isset($_REQUEST['productID']));
```

if you check it you will find the output is true\false as returned by `isset`

```
var_dump($id); //true
```

what you should use is:

```
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['productID'])){ //maybe also check its a number and or valid range
$id=$_REQUEST['productID'];
}
```